# Questions cross-posted from other question sites?

Tags: discussion

If someone posts a question which has previously been posted at another site, is it appropriate to post a linkback?

Example: [Were bodies shipped overseas to be buried?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14298/1006) which has a link to unanswered questions at Quora.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the Quora question, which was really a title-only question with no details, has since been edited out of the G&FH SE question by one of our users.

I think that was the correct action to take in this instance.

In general, I think:

- cross-posting between Stack Exchange sites should not be done - just ask on one SE site at a time
- cross-posting between G&FH SE, and other genealogy Q&A sites and forums is OK when it looks likely to result in a net gain of quality content on our site
- posting a link here to another site where it looks like the purpose may be to try and have our users visit that site to answer their questions rather than ours is something that should be discouraged